# Editing default value of dropdown menu in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently trying to edit a view in the backend of a wordpress install I have. I am using a plugin called Bookly, it presents a drop down box with a list of values to select from. It gets this information from the DB.

Here is image for you to see what it looks like at the moment.

[image]

I want to change the default value from Employee to Reliever, but continue pulling from the Employee DB.

This is what the code looks like for this drop down mean.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control bookly-js-chosen-select" id="bookly-filter-staff" data-placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( \Bookly\Lib\Utils\Common::getTranslatedOption( 'bookly_l10n_label_employee' ) ) ?>">
        <option value="-1"></option>
             <?php foreach ( $staff_members as $staff ) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $staff['id'] ?>"><?php esc_html_e( $staff['full_name'] ) ?></option>
             <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

I under stand the for loop however I am not sure how to change so that it shows "Reliever" instead of "Employee".

### Update

I have found comms file. This is the method that's being called.

```
public static function getTranslatedOption( $option_name )
    {
        return self::getTranslatedString( $option_name, get_option( $option_name ) );
    }
```

calls

```
public static function getTranslatedString( $name, $original_value = '', $language_code = null )
    {
        return apply_filters( 'wpml_translate_single_string', $original_value, 'bookly', $name, $language_code );
    }
```

What should I look at next?

Comment: I think that Employee is placeholder and not option. However you need to check this on your end...

Comment: No experience with Bookly, but.. Just out of curiosity have you tried changing getTranslatedOption( 'bookly_l10n_label_employee' ) to getTranslatedOption( 'bookly_l10n_label_reliever' ) or removing that PHP script entirely, and just doing: data-placeholder="Reliever"

Comment: So I have not tired either. I tried looking for the Common file but have not found it yet.
I am worried if I make edits to this Common file that it will break the Bookly DB.. 
I primarily develop in objective c and am working on this project to help my brother with an idea he has. So am still getting my head around how alot of this works and interacts. For instance where would I look for a plugin DB?

Comment: I have figured it out.
I found strings to update in the install file.
Also in some of the views that i have updated they dont change untill i uninstall the plugin then reinstall it.

I would like to know if there is a way to update this witout having to reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

This would set defaul value to "Reliever"

```
<option value="<?php echo $staff['id'] ?>" <?php echo (esc_html_e( $staff['full_name'] )=='Reliever')? 'selected':''; ?> ><?php esc_html_e( $staff['full_name'] ) ?></option>`
```

Comment: Sorry but this did not work now i see
Employee
>Reliever Test
>> Reliever Test